# Getting filename from path using QString basic functions

Tags: qt, path, qstring

There's some path as QString:

```
QString path = "C:/bla/blah/x/y/file.xls";
```

I thought that maybe getting last offset of `/` would be a good start. I could then use [`right`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#right) method (no pun intended) to get everything after that character:

```
path = path.right(path.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

or in a more compatible way:

```
path = path.right(std::max(path.lastIndexOf("\\"), path.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

Those both have the same bad result:

```
ah/x/y/file.xls
```

What's wrong here? Obviously the path is getting cut too soon, but it's even weirder it's not cut at any of `/` at all.

Comment: `QFileInfo( "C:/bla/blah/x/y/file.xls" ).fileName();`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `QString` method you want is `mid`, not `right` (`right` counts from the end of the string):

```
path = path.mid(path.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

`mid` has a second parameter, but when it's omitted you get the rightmost part of the string.

And for a cleaner / more universal code:

```
QFileInfo fi("C:/bla/blah/x/y/file.xls");
QString fileName = fi.fileName();
```

NB `QFileInfo` doesn't query the file system when it doesn't have to, and here it doesn't have to because all the infos are in the string.

Answer (score 1):

From QString::right():

"Returns a substring that contains the n rightmost characters of the string."

You're using the index as a count. You'd have to use .size() - .indexOf().